# how can I upload image file on server with ionic?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, storage

I have searched 'file transfer' and 'firebase storage'. but It didn't run.

```
const uploadTask = imageRef.put(this.selectedPhoto);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED:
            console.log('Upload is paused');
            break;
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING:
            console.log('Upload is running');
            break;
        }

      }, function(error) {

        console.log('firebase error : ' + error);

      }, function() {

        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
          console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        });
      });
```

The log doesn't appear.
So I don't know what to do and how to do..
Please help me..

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example code. Use FileTransfer plugin.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
     constructor{
        private camera: Camera,
        private transfer: FileTransfer,
        private file: File,
      ) {
    }
    takePhoto(){
      const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        correctOrientation: true
      }

      this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
       // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
       // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
       this.uploadPhoto(imageData);  //call your function to upload image
      }, (err) => {
       // Handle error
      });
    }

    uploadPhoto(path){
       const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
           let options: FileUploadOptions = {
              fileKey: 'file',
              fileName: '.png',
              chunkedMode: false,
              //mimeType: "image/jpeg",
           }
           fileTransfer.upload(path, 'yourUrl.com/imageupload', options)
              .then((data) => {
               console.log(JSON.parse(data.response));
               let res = JSON.parse(data.response);
               if (res.status == 1) {
                  tconsole.log('Image Uploaded successfull');
               }      
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
```